# How do I remove estimated shipping and tax from Magento 2.02

Tags: magento2

I've scoured the interwebs and have found some information on how to do this but it looks like files and method to accomplish this have changed from 2.0->2.02.

I'm using the standard Luma theme.

all/any help appreciated.

Comment: This will give you errors, you can find the answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart

Answer (score 3):

For this requirement,you need to go `checkout_cart_index.xml` file and remove this code:

...

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="cart/shipping.phtml">
....
  </argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```

Or use :

You can use this section using  tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true" /> <!-- use this code -->
```

for remove this section .

See how to use 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_rmv

### Update answer at

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283648/4564

Comment: Great I'll give this a go and report back...is this in the xml file in ./vendor/magento/module-checkout/? or another directory. I have about 15 files named this

Comment: Be careful, as this approach will likely cause JavaScript errors. Better to do this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113151/567

Comment: Create virtual/digital products. :)

Comment: After using this getting js error. The better solution is here  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191712/31729

Comment: I got js error as well... thanks @Manish for the info

Answer (score 0):

Create Your theme

add below file `checkout_cart_index.xml` at `/app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>

                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```