# Magento 2 How to remove shipping rate estimation in shopping cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping

Sometimes the estimation of shipping showed

> Shipping (undefined - undefined)

so I want to remove this row of thing. How can I remove it? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 remove "Estimate shipping costs and tax" from cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this question in magento stack exchange:

[Magento 2 remove "Estimate shipping costs and tax" from cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart)

Comment: question is just remove the undefined-undefined comming after shippinng calculate . He is not wana remove shipping calulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem so many times.

Are you using the any 3rd party extension? You would need to make check in collect rates() method for undefinded- undefined tile or price.

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own custom module

Comment: need to check in  your custom module  to check what shipping title is coming. Put in condition then rest code in else part.

Comment: it's useless for me even if it shows correctly. how can i remove it?

Comment: show the code  of custom module