# Remove shipping costs in cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, shipping-methods, totals

In default our Magento2 installation shows the shipping costs ([screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/192557/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-31%2016-58-32.png)) in the cart (even for unkown/not logged in users). We would like to not show the shipping costs in the calculation in the cart, but I can't find any configuration for it.

So the problem is not the "Estimate Shipping Costs" box, but the fact that the shipping costs need not be added until the checkout.

If I look in the source I do see this comment `<!-- ko if: isExcludingDisplayed() -->` around the `<tr>` for said shipping costs, which leads me to believe there is a setting to turn it off at this point.

But where? How? I could hide it with CSS/rip it out of the HTML, but that doesn't affect the calculation.

FYI: We have set up a single Shipping Method with Tablerates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 remove "Estimate shipping costs and tax" from cart](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart)

Comment: Nope, found that one too. That question is about the "Estimate shipping and tax" box, it's different from this one. In my case the shipping costs 'just' don't need to be calculated at the cart, but only in checkout.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm currently having the same task.

Comment: @GielBerkers It's a while back ago, and I'm no longer on this project, but if I remember correctly we fixed it by enabling ALL the shipping method/tax options in the backend. Even if an option says "Yes" or "No" but is disabled because it's the "default" setting; enable it anyway. That eventually worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme add the following xml into Magento_Checkout -> layout -> checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I tried with Magento CE 2.1.1

Comment: This didn't work for me on 2.1.3 & 2.1.4