# magento 2 estimate shipping and tax disappeard

Tags: magento2, cart

After some updates and an installation of myparcel module for some reason my "estimate shipping and tax" disappeard in cart.

How can i enable it again?

Comment: Check if any of your custom module has removed it in that way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart

Comment: Unfortunatly thats not it, i know the module that influence because when i uninstall it the problem is gone. But no XML overriding in that module