# Removing Country and RegionID from Estimates and Tax

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, shipping, order-summary

I am working on the checkout a lot currently, but I cannot figure out how to exclude Country and Postal code from the Estimate Shipping and Tax.

[image]

There are a lot of other suggestions and solutions like this one:

[Magento 2 remove "Estimate shipping costs and tax" from cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart?noredirect=1&lq=1)

These solutions are unsatisfying though. The delivery cost within our country of service will be the same everywhere. This fix excludes the Shipping cost from the totals calculation and I think customers want to see the total cost of their order before they checkout.

I found out that if you leave **shopping-estimation.html** completely empty it will do exactly what I want, however I find this fix to be very dirty and it will only work when I leave it empty within the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart`
directory.

I believe I need to overwrite the file that calls **shopping-estimation.html**, however I am unable to locate it. I know it has to be within the **module-checkout** directory.

Here is `shipping-estimation.html` from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart`

```
<form method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
    <fieldset class="fieldset estimate">
        <legend class="legend">
            <span data-bind="text: isVirtual ? $t('Estimate Tax') : $t('Estimate Shipping and Tax') "></span>
        </legend><br>
        <p class="field note" data-bind="text: isVirtual ? $t('Enter your billing address to get a tax estimate.') : $t('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.')"></p>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-fieldsets') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have made a mistake, Country and Region can be removed by placing a file called `shipping-estimation.html`

into:

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart
```

for it to work **shipping-estimation.html** has to be completely empty.

Hope this can help someone!