# how to remove shipping cost from magento2 checkout summery

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

[image: I want to remove the price $0.00 and want to put the static text instead of shipping method text]

I am a beginner to Magento 2 and based on my some research I see that this whole block of cart subtotal is coming from

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/totals.html

Here some Knockout JS code is mentioned to getTemplate() JS function, which I don't know how to debug and reach to the HTML file from the data is coming

though the file

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/shupping.html

Looks like containing the data that I want to modify but when I make any changes in it and even flush the cache, and flush the static files. But none of the changes are appearing there.

Can anyone help me on this please? Do I have to run static content deploy to show the changes?

Comment: If it’s I knockout templates you must clear navigator cache

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191712/34118 - Removing the block will break the summary section, at least in the few times I've tried in v2.1.x

Comment: @Pmclain thanks for the comment. I do not want to remove the complete block, just a price $0.00 appearing there. I still want to show the texts.

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet can you guide me how can I clear navigator search? thanks for help.

Comment: Crtl shift supp you can clear navigator cache

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet Sorry It did not help.

Comment: @Pmclain I changed as per described in the post nothing changed. here I can see clearly the same data that it looks like on HTML perspective with the same class and same information. 
https://i.imgur.com/43oLYcV.png

from file 
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/shupping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This price and Shipping carrier name is coming from **JS** file and not the **PHTML** file. you can find **JS** file at below location

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

Answer (score 0):

You can remove block by using code in your checkout_index.xml layout file like:

[Remove block from layout in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80425/remove-block-from-layout-in-magento-2)

""