# Magento 2: Show loader in cart page summary after remove shipping estimation

Tags: magento2, cart, summary

I successfully remove the shipping estimation in Magento 2 cart page summary using this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191712/84142):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

when the page first load in cart page summary, the order total will take some time to display, but there is no loader that indicates the order summary is being loaded

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a loader by override/extend:

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/totals.phtml
```

```
...<div id="cart-totals" class="cart-totals" data-bind="scope:'block-totals'">...

    <div data-bind="if: isLoading">
        <div class="load indicator"></div>
    </div>

...<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->...
```

If you don't like the overlay loader, just change `load indicator` classes with a custom classes.