# Magento 2 Remove Estimate Shipping costs and Tax on cart page based on condition

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-tax

I want to show/hide "Estimate Shipping costs and Tax" based on customer group.

I just do not write to css that hide block as it is bad practice. Is there any way we can disable component based on condition or remove block on xml based?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look, at [Magento 2 remove "Estimate shipping costs and tax" from cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart)

If you can implement layout concept to the Block class then you get can add the condition.

`checkout.cart.shipping` is the layout name of the block class  `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping` and  `getJsLayout` function/method is responsible for render of `Estimate Shipping costs and Tax` section.

If you will add able to `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>` to  the output of **`getJsLayout`**  then you will get solutions.

And at block class, we can get the current user group code by `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context::getValue`

So, just need to add create [***after plugin***](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping::getJsLayout` then  put of customer grou checking then condition at here,

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Checkout;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

class Shipping {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext     
     ) {

         $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }
    public function afterGetJsLayout(
            \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping $subject,
            $result
    ) {

        $allowedCustomgroupIds  = [0,5,2];

        $currrentCustomGruopId = $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_GROUP);

        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        //  if customer group DOES NOT match then donot show "Estimate Shipping costs and Tax"

        if (!in_array($currrentCustomGruopId , $allowedCustomgroupIds) && isset($result['components']['block-summary'])) {
            //Disable Estimate Shipping costs and Tax 
            $result['components']['block-summary']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
        }

        return json_encode($result, JSON_HEX_TAG);
    }

}
```